# SQL Statement with bad performance, although using index

Tags: mysql

I have a simple SQL statement in my application:

```
  SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE key_event_id, MAX(report_ts) AS max_ts
  FROM `key_event_reports`
  WHERE report_model_id = 2 
  GROUP BY key_event_id;
```

The `key_event_reports` table is of medium size (~ 17M rows), this is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `key_event_reports` (
  `key_event_report_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `report_model_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `key_event_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `title_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `report_ts` datetime NOT NULL,
  `report_time` time NOT NULL,
  `total` int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pos` int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `neg` int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `smooth_total` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `smooth_pos` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `smooth_neg` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `buzz` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sentiment` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`key_event_report_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `key_event_id_4` (`key_event_id`,`report_model_id`,`title_id`,`report_ts`),
  KEY `report_model_id` (`key_event_id`,`report_time`),
  KEY `report_model_id_2` (`report_model_id`,`key_event_id`,`report_ts`),
  KEY `key_event_id` (`key_event_id`,`report_model_id`,`report_time`,`title_id`,`smooth_total`),
  KEY `key_event_id_3` (`key_event_id`,`report_model_id`,`report_time`,`title_id`,`smooth_pos`),
  KEY `key_event_id_2` (`key_event_id`,`report_model_id`,`report_time`,`title_id`,`smooth_neg`),
  KEY `get_latest_report` (`report_model_id`,`report_ts`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=16967636 ;
```

The report_model_id is always 2 (there are no other models in the db yet, but this can change soon) and there are 10 different key_events which get reported every 10 minutes.

This query takes very long without caching (ca 20 seconds). The problem gets worse, when the query above is used as a sub-query in a larger statement:

```
SET @report_model_id = 2;
SET @message_id = ?;
SET @title_id = ?
SET @min_score = 5;

SET @min_message_id = ( 
    SELECT MIN(message_id)  
    FROM `messages`  
    WHERE msg_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) 
); 

SELECT 
    ke.key_event_id AS key_event_id, 
    COALESCE(kermmid.message_id, MIN(mhke.message_id)) AS max_message_id, 
    ker_max.max_ts AS last_report_ts 
FROM `key_events` ke
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT key_event_id, MAX(report_ts) AS max_ts
    FROM `key_event_reports`
    WHERE report_model_id = 2 
    GROUP BY key_event_id
) ker_max
    ON ( ker_max.key_event_id = ke.key_event_id )
    LEFT JOIN `key_event_reports` ker 
        ON (
            ker.key_event_id = ke.key_event_id 
            AND ker.report_model_id = @report_model_id 
            AND ker.title_id = @title_id 
            AND ker.report_ts = @actcurrent 
        ) 
    LEFT JOIN `key_event_report_max_message_ids` kermmid 
        ON (
            kermmid.key_event_id = ker.key_event_id 
            AND kermmid.report_model_id = ker.report_model_id 
            AND kermmid.report_ts = ker.report_ts 
        ) 
    LEFT JOIN `messages_has_key_events` mhke 
        ON ( 
            mhke.key_event_id = ke.key_event_id 
            AND mhke.title_id = @title_id 
            AND mhke.message_id > @min_message_id 
            AND mhke.message_id < @message_id 
            AND mhke.score > @min_score 
        ) 
    GROUP BY 
        ke.key_event_id;
```

If I use the sub-query in this, the execution time goes from ~50ms to >20s too.

What could be the reason for this and how could I possibly optimize my statement or DB structure?

Comment: Which index is the query using?

Comment: This is what `EXPLAIN` shows: 
SIMPLE; key_event_reports; ref; report_model_id_2,get_latest_report; report_model_id_2; 4; const; 8873835; Using where, Using index

Comment: I find this behavior very strange, imo the `report_model_id_2` index should fit for this query: take the path of report_model_id 2 in the first index layer (n), take all the key_event_ids(m) in the second layer and for each take the max of all report_ts (l) in the third layer. This should be an easy walk through the index tree, so it's O(log(n)+log(m)+log(l)), which would not take 20 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an index on `(report_model_id,key_event_id,report_ts)` and adding `report_model_id` to the group by. That should allow it to use [group by optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html).

```
SELECT key_event_id, MAX(report_ts) AS max_ts
FROM `key_event_reports`
WHERE report_model_id = 2 
GROUP BY report_model_id, key_event_id
```

I'm still trying to figure out a way for the rest of the query... Does the inner SELECT need to be a LEFT JOIN or an INNER JOIN would do?

Edit: I missed the fact that you already have the index so you just need to add the field to GROUP BY.

Comment: This solved the problem perfectly. Both queries are running very smoothly now. Thank you for saving my day!

Answer (score 2):

For the "why", my guess would be MySQL query caching.

MySQL will cache query results under certain circumstances to speed up repeated queries. If the data changes It would have to rerun the query. I don't know how it handles subqueries.

Comment: This seems to be right, when I use the SQL_NO_CACHE option the query always takes 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your query is already using this index.

```
`report_model_id_2` (`report_model_id`,`key_event_id`,`report_ts`)
```

It contains all the information your query needs, so MySQL is able to satisfy your query by doing a range scan on this index rather than on the whole table. The good news is you've optimized the query pretty well.  That's the bad news too.

Does it makes sense to create a summary table, and set up an event in your MySQL database to update the summary table from the detail data once in a while?  This would only be true if it's not disastrous for your application if the result of this query runs a little behind.

You might also rig up a trigger to update the summary table, if you must have this information perfectly in sync with your detail table.

Comment: Unfortunately this is used for real-time data, so execution time matters a lot in this case. We get a live feed of messages, which are analyzed in real-time with scores falling into different groups, giving aggregated scores to these groups.